# What is the reason to weigh oneself during a workout?

Tags: workout

I saw people weigh themselves *during* a workout at a gym.

Is there a reason to do that? 
(besides the obvious wanting to know how much water one have lost and be able to drink accordingly?).

Curiously, some do it multiple times.

Comment: Was this person in the middle of running or some other continuous activity?

Comment: No, in between sets of exercises.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have a condition that requires specific monitoring and fluid intake, weighing yourself during a workout is of an academic interest, nothing more. There are studies that show a certain amount of weight loss during exercise can have a detrimental effect, but just replacing fluid doesn't account for the muscle glycogen loss and other factors.

If you are monitoring weight for gain/loss, once a day under the same conditions is the best way to track it, anything more than that is just for personal interest.

Comment: what would be a possible condition, that would not prevent you from doing workouts?

Comment: Just one? On any antidiuretic hormone, water I&O has to be monitored to prevent water toxicity. CHF, early renal failure, a few others.

Answer (score 0):

I personally do it just because I do not own a scale and I have down time before sets.  I'm sure a lot of people do it for similar reasons.

Comment: moved the embedded question in your answer to a comment on the main question.